# Populate dropdown in cell with list of tabs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to populate a dropdown within a Google Sheets cell with a list of the tabs (sheets) inside the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to the script editor and save the project:

```
function get_sheets() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(function(x) {return x.getName();});}
```

Then you can add it to a cell. Here I select A2 as the dropdown formular. I simply select the range of column B.

[image: Create dropdown form.]

And voila:

[image: Finished dropdown.]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools > Script editor`

Paste into `Code.gs`:

```js
/*** return sheet names for active document
 * @customfunction
 */
function sheetnms() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(function(x) {return x.getName();});
}
```

Save as a project.

Go back the Google sheet.

Enter `=sheetnms()` into a cell.

When creating a data validation, get the list from the range of cells with the sheet names.

**Note:** there may be some delay for the list to update.